# Difference between ;& and ;; in a bash script

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I'm copying a bash script from a Linux box to my Mac laptop and in the process, the script has started complaining about the usage of `;&`.

With the error:

> ./build.sh: line 122: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
>   ./build.sh: line 122: `                    ;&'

There's a few uses in the script, but a short one is:

```
case ${OPTION} in
    xxx)
        export DEVICES=xxx
         ;;
    yyy)
        export DEVICES=yyy
         ;;
    *)
        echo "${OPTION}: Unknown device type:  use xxx|yyy"
        exit 1
        ;&
    esac
;;
```

I've replaced all usages of `;&` with `;;` and I *think* that everything is ok, but I'm still curious what I've done. **What's the difference between semicolon-ampersand and double semicolon in case statements?**

Comment: The reason this doesn't work on OS X is that it's a bash 4 feature, and OS X ships with bash 3.2 (because they refuse to ship code licensed GPLv3).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for that insight: it appears that the out-of-date software on OSX is _by design_.   I found more information about this policy here: [Apple’s great GPL purge](http://meta.ath0.com/2012/02/05/apples-great-gpl-purge/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> Using ;& in place of ;; causes execution to continue with the list
>   associated
>                 with the next set of patterns.

Since `;&` occurs on the last pattern in the `case` statement, it should make no difference in that script.

Comment: In other words, `;&` mimics the fall-through behavior of a C switch statements. The reason it doesn't work on OS X is that OS X comes with an antiquated version of Bash.

Comment: @thatotherguy: I wouldn't call 3.2 "antiquated." It wasn't that long ago that you still had to write highly-portable shell scripts using `test` instead of `[` because there were still boxes out there with `/bin/sh` as the original 1977 Bourne shell. You can't blame Apple for refusing to ship the GPL3'd Bash 4, since that would prevent its use on the iPhone due to the anti-Tivoization provision.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Well, Bash 3.2 was released 9 years ago, which is quite a while in software terms. At the time, there was no such thing as Android and iPhone, and IE 6 on Windows XP was the state of the art. (Also, I think you'd be amazed at what I can blame Apple for :P)

Comment: @thatotherguy: `bash --version` says 2007 on my Mac, the same year the iPhone came out. It was in development for [about three years](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphone#History_and_availability) prior to the keynote.

Comment: @thatotherguy if it doesn't work, how does one port a script to OSX in that case?

Comment: @kimi On Mac OSX, you can use `homebrew` to install modern software including `bash`.  See, for example, [How to update bash on Mac OS X Yosemite](https://superuser.com/questions/857250/how-to-update-bash-on-mac-os-x-yosemite).